# apache-spark startup error on alpine linux docker

Tags: apache-spark, docker, alpine-linux

*I followed https://www.anchormen.nl/spark-docker/ and 
When i executed the command ,apache startup fails saying "--" is not recognized.
I am very new to spark.Requesting help from our trusted community members.

```
bash /opt/spark/sbin/start-master.sh
starting org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master, logging to /opt/spark/logs/spark--org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-e6b8f9219a40.out
failed to launch: nice -n 0 /opt/spark/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master --host e6b8f9219a40 --port 7077 --webui-port 8080
  nohup: can't execute '--': No such file or directory
full log in /opt/spark/logs/spark--org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-e6b8f9219a40.out
```

*
Only difference from the article is that i used alpine linux,which am restricted to.

to verify i tried to cat the log file..and got the same error. alpine linux in docker is not recognizing "--" .am i doing something wrong?

[SOLVED] thanks Robert.

if anyone looking for answer add the following in your docker-file

```
RUN apk update && apk upgrade && apk add curl ca-certificates tar supervisor bash procps coreutils
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is here in this [line](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/2ab8551e79e1655c406c358b21c0a1e719f498be/sbin/spark-daemon.sh#L128)

The thing is that the `alpine` image comes with `busybox`, which is a replacement of many commands including `nohup` and `ps`. So alpine comes with a non-gnu `nohup` which cannot handle that `--`, and a `ps` which cannot handle `-p`.

So, install `coreutils` and `procps` packages before any call to apache spark scripts in order to have the version of `nohup` and `ps` that you need.

In Dockerfile or container command line:

```
RUN apk --update add coreutils procps
```

Comment: awesome.. thank you.. I knew it comes with busybox commands so i was only updating some commands. ended up using RUN apk update && apk upgrade && apk add curl ca-certificates tar supervisor bash procps coreutils